# Where the point in controllers where a order is created?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am working on a prestashop modification, I need to create an order in other platform when a prestashop order is created. The previous programmer put the code on the method "initContent" of "controllers/front/OrderConfirmationController.php" controller. The problem is that point allow duplication of orders and other derivated problems. I think that could be a better place to do that.

I would ask where is the better place to put that code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create the order in the other platform, not depending on the current order status, you could override the PaymentModule::validateOrder.

```
abstract class PaymentModule extends PaymentModuleCore
{
     public function validateOrder($id_cart, $id_order_state, $amount_paid, $payment_method = 'Unknown',
         $message = null, $extra_vars = array(), $currency_special = null, $dont_touch_amount = false,
         $secure_key = false, Shop $shop = null)
     {
          parent::validateOrder($id_cart, $id_order_state, $amount_paid, $payment_method, $message, $extra_vars, $currency_special, $dont_touch_amount = false, $secure_key, $shop);
          // use $this->currentOrder to get current id_order and create order on the other platform
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Need I to do this for each payment mode?

Comment: No, unless some payment has defined the validateOrder. Each payment module already calls the PaymentModule::validateOrder, to validate the order (create it from the cart). For example, class BankWire extends PaymentModule and doesn't have any validateOrder function, so it will call the parent validateOrder.